# How to get to key in MongoDB?

Tags: json, mongodb

I have JSON like this:

```
{
    "array": [
        {
            "object1": {
                "key1":"value1",
                "key2":"value2",
                "key3":"value3"
            }
        },
        {
            "object2": {
                "key1":"value1",
                "key2":"value2",
                "key3":"value3"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get to the key inside object in MongoDB by db.collection.find(), but I can't figure out what to type inside parentheses. I tried: `db.collection.find({"array":{"object1.key1":"value1"}});`but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `db.collection.find({"array.object1.key1":"value1"})`. This will return the document where there is match on that key. To return the matched array element you use `db.collection.find({"array.object1.key1":"value1"}, {array.$":1})`

Comment: It's working, but you forgot about quotation mark: `{"array.$":1})` Thanks a lot! ;)